# How to use async/await in nodejs 10?

Tags: firebase, function

```
  router.get('/test', function(req, res, next) {

    const offerwallHistory_snapshot = db.collection('offerwallHistory').doc(uid).collection('offerwallHistory').where('completedRewardKey', '==', event_id).get();      

    if (offerwallHistory_snapshot.empty) {
        const pointHistory_snapshot = db.collection('pointHistory').doc(uid).collection('pointHistory').orderBy('pointDate', 'desc').limit(1).get();
        if (pointHistory_snapshot.empty) {//없다
            ... 
        }

        db.collection('pointHistory').doc(uid).collection('pointHistory').add(newPointHistory);
        db.collection('users').doc(uid).update({point: addTotalPoint});
        db.collection('offerwallHistory').doc(uid).collection('offerwallHistory').add(offerwallHistory_data); //오퍼월 히스토리 데이터 추가
        db.collection('adminPointHistory').add(adminPointHistory_data); //관리자포인트히스토리 데이터 추가
        setDailyPointStatus(reward, 12);
        return res.send(event_id + ":OK").status(200);
    }else{
        return res.send(event_id + "else OK").status(200);
    }

    return res.send(":OK").status(200);
});


function setDailyPointStatus(point, type){

    ....

    try {
        await db.runTransaction(async (t) => { <===========error

        });
        console.log('Transaction success!');
    } catch (e) {
        console.log('Transaction failure:', e);
    }
}
```

i don't know what's the problem......please help me....

when deploy on my console there is error "error  Parsing error: Unexpected token db"

my node version 10
What's the problem?
help me... :(

Comment: Can you share complete code? Where is `db` defined?

Comment: db works fine without await

Comment: var db = admin.firestore();

Comment: Is the parent function async ?

Comment: shared complete code. please check again~

Comment: Try making it `async function setDailyPointStatus(point, type)` ?

Comment: not working.....[ error  Parsing error: Unexpected token function ]